# How to dismiss popover in UIAutomation

Tags: ios7, ui-automation

I cant seem to find a way to make UIAutomation dismiss a popover.

When i do this

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().toolbar().buttons()["Sort By"].tap();
```

The popover is displayed

Next i do this

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().popover().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[sortType].tap();
```

to select a item in the popover

Next i did

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().toolbar().buttons()["Sort By"].tap();
```

Hoping that it would be dismissed. But instead i received a error

```
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: target.frontMostApp().toolbar().buttons()["Sort By"] could not be tapped on line 186 of test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var window = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
window.tap();
```